# Why link components render outside the page on Chrome but are ok on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox

I have some link components in my React web application that should only be displayed when the user hovers over a certain element on the webpage. The website ([sepsol.github.io](https://sepsol.github.io)) loads fine on Firefox, but when I try to load it on Chrome I don't see my link components. I inspected the page and if you look closely, you see that the elements are outside the page.

**Here's the problem in action:**

[image]

LEFT: Chrome  |  RIGHT: Firefox

--

**React Code:**

I don't know where the problem lies, so I'm unable to put any specific code snippet here. I'll link my whole React repository instead:
https://github.com/sepsol/sepsol.github.io/tree/react-code

Comment: The problem seems to be with the animation, its showing initially, it hides after a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container around those links is absolutely positioned and is looking to find the nearest parent to position itself. Firefox is using an implicit parent rule giving you the result you want, while Chrome needs the parent to be explicitly defined. What you need is to declare `work-card-container` as a parent. Then, the absolute positioning of the link container will be within the bounds of this newly defined parent.

Add the following:

```css
.work-card-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! I'm gonna mark your answer as accepted, but before that can you also please update your answer to help me fix the "hashtag" links next to `section-title`s as well? --- EDIT: fixed that as well with the help of your description!

Comment: @SepSol Same solution. Add `position: relative` to `.section-title` as well.